# How do I export my iPhone's call logs?

Tags: iphone, ios, call, history

How can I get export the call log (incoming and outgoing calls) from my iPhone, preferably as a CSV file?

I found

- [MobileLog](http://www.ixtension.com/) Jailbreak needed, $9.99
- [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) $19.95
- [calLog](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/callog/id327883585?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) Doesn't work with iOS 5, $9.99

but none is free and/or open source and none offers a command line interface to automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

How about [iPhone Call List](http://web.archive.org/web/20140705111231/http://www.imacsoft.com/downloads/affiliate-575053/m-iphone-call-list-to-mac-transfer.dmg)?  (You can download a free copy in the link)

I haven't tried it myself yet (I'll as soon as I get home), but it seems the app you're looking for!

> iPhone call list to Mac Transfer fully support latest iOS 4.2, iPad,
>   iPhone OS 3.1.3, iPod touch FW 3.1.3, iPod nano 5G FW 1.0 and iTunes
>   10.1.

Comment: It suits a one time need. I clarified my question that I really want something with a command line interface. I was hoping that somebody wrote a script or something.

Answer (score 1):

Syncios works great for me, and it's free.
https://www.syncios.com/

Connect your device, select Information -> Call History -> Save.

It saves as a CSV, which I then open and manipulate with xl macros.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Syncios application (version 7.0.1 - current as of today) states: "Sorry, Syncios doesn't support loading iOS 13 call history." Doh!