# iPhone: list of calls of a contact

Tags: iphone, call, history

On iPhone, how can I see the list of calls (incoming and outgoing) with a certain contact?

Tapping the last call in the call history only shows the last (sometimes two or three last) call(s).

iPhone SE, iOS 13.2.2

Comment: Carrier might be able to help

Comment: [How do I export my iPhone's call logs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/how-do-i-export-my-iphones-call-logs?rq=1)

Comment: @ankii is there a way to see the list on the phone, without using a PC?